# Angular Routing from standalone component to other components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In angular 15 the standalone components were introduced, I as long as I use Ionic 7 all my routes are stored in the `app.component.ts`. How is it now possible to create a `routing.ts` file in another component, as I want to refer to other components here for example. is this still possible or do I have to do it all in the `app.routes.ts` now. Unfortunately I have no source code as i have no starting point.

For example I want to be redirected from the path `localhost:8100` to `localhost:8100/home`. I can define this in the `app.routes.ts`. But if I want to be redirected from the `localhost:8100/home` to the `localhost:8100/home/introduction` I would have had a home-routing.module.ts before the standalone components, in my home component where I could make a redirect to the `introduction` component.

How does this work now?

Comment: I have a "test" project where I only use standalone for everything. 0 modules 
https://github.com/ferranJS/discordish if you are curious